# How to increase concurrent performance of Buffer Pool in database systems?

Tags: database, multithreading, concurrency, paging

In database system tutorials, like textbook *Database System Concepts*, there is a module called Buffer Pool / Buffer Manager / Pager / whatever. I didn't see much detail about it, so I'm curious how do you increase the **concurrent** performance of it?

For example, let's say we have a Trie Index. If we do the paging inside the trie, without the buffer pool, we can easily have multiple threads concurrently load or evict leaf nodes: all you need to do is to acquire shared locks of nodes from the top to the bottom and the exclusive lock of the parent of the leaf node.

However, if you instead let the buffer pool to handle the paging things, then I suppose you might need to acquire the exclusive lock of the buffer pool. Then, there is only a single thread can load or evict pages at the same time.

Actually, I have tried this in a database implementation. The old version doesn't have a buffer pool and manages the paging things in the trie index. And the new version has a buffer pool does the job instead of the trie index itself. There is a big lock protecting the hashmap that maps Page ID to the corresponding page in the buffer pool. The single thread test is 40% faster, however, with 10 concurrent threads, 5x slower!

I guess lock-free data structures may help? But I also guess that's going to be hard to think it straight. So how do you guys design and implement the buffer pool? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem thanks to [the discussion here (in Chinese, sorry)](https://www.zhihu.com/question/67850850/answer/257301293). The solution is quite simple, just shard the buffer manager. Each page is delegated to a shard by hashing the page number. As long as this hash function results in a uniform distribution, the probability of multiple threads waiting on the same lock will be low.

In my case, I divided the buffer manager into 128 shards and the hash function is just `page_no % 128`, with 10 threads, the result of a simple benchmark looks quite amazing:

- with Sharded Buffer Manager: 7.73s
- with Buffer Manager: 123s
- without Buffer Manager, i.e. the trie does the paging itself: 19.7s

BTW, MySQL seems to also take this approach (correct me if I misunderstood it): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-buffer-pools.html